# For Loops and if statements in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to get row values is certain conditions are met

here is the code

```
response='108'
group="MAMA"
optout='False'

for row in merged_df:
        if row==response & row==group & row==optout:
            print(merged_df['phone'])
```

My dataframe looks like so

```
phone       group   County  PNC/ANC Facility Name   Optedout    Facility Code
25470000000 MAMA    Orange  PNC     Main Centre       FALSE      112
25470000000 MAMA    Orange  PNC     Main Centre       FALSE      112
25470000010 MAMA    Orange  PNC     Centre            FALSE      108
25470000020 MAMA    Orange  PNC     Centre            FALSE      108
25470000000 MAMA    Orange  PNC     Main Centre       FALSE      112
```

This is the error I get

```
    read_masterFacility()
  File "readsheet.py", line 48, in read_masterFacility
    if row==response & row==group & row==optout:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'str'
```

desired output

```
25470000010 
25470000020
```

How can I do this better??

Comment: as much as possible try and avoid native python for loops... u will get much faster code when u use Pandas or numpy's built in functions. Also, kindly post data and not pics, with expected output (also data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because `&` is bitwise comparison. Also the second problem is if `merged_df` is a dataframe, `for row in merged_df` will only iterate over it's column names. You should do it like this:

**Edited code:**

```py
phones = merged_df.loc[(merged_df['Facility Code'] == response) & (merged_df['group'] == group) & (merged_df['Optedout'] == optout)]['phone'].values
print(phones)
```

Comment: I don't get any error but I also don't get any output

Comment: Try `optout = 'FALSE'` instead of `'False`', as it's `FALSE` in the dataframe

Comment: I did so but still, no output and no errors
desired output
```25470000010 
  25470000020
```

Comment: returns an empty list ```[ ]```

Comment: You sure Facility Code is integer and not string?

Comment: Thank you so much...that was what I was missing

Answer (score 0):

You will want the following:

```
if ((row["Facility Code"]==response and row["group"]==group) and row["optedout"]=optout):
```

This works because you are checking the values in the row for each of those columns. You need to specify the column you are checking against. '&' is also a bitwise and in Python.

In addition, I think you want to print out row["phone"].

Comment: I get this error
```TypeError: string indices must be integers```

Comment: what is the type of row: is merged_df a dataframe?   You can check with type(merged_df)

Comment: merged_df is a dataframe...the dtype  of all the columns is object

Comment: Regarding the not getting output - is it supposed to be print(row['phone']) in the last row?

Comment: I just wanted to print all phone numbers in my df if all conditions are true